# My python code runs a few times but as soon as I close my computer or do something else, it doesn't run again

Tags: python, interpreter

Running this code a few times presents no issues. Upon attempting to show a friend, it doesn't work. It just hangs after the input. It's worked quite a few times before but never again unfortunately.

I've tried rewriting the code in brackets, rewriting the code to a local directory instead of the Google Drive folder I have and I've even tried rewriting from scratch in regular notepad. All this was tried in case some sort of encoding issue had occured. No such luck. I figure something is wrong with the interpreter but I'm not sure how to remedy the situation.

```
def bin2dec():
    bin = []
    a = int(input("What number are you converting to binary?: "))
    while a > 0:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            bin.insert(0, 0)
            a = a/2
        elif a % 2 == 1:
            bin.insert(0, 1)
            a = a/2-0.5
    else:
        #repetition
        print("Your binary equivalent is:", bin)
        repeat = input("Would you like to convert another binary number?: ")
        if repeat == "yes":
            bin2dec()

bin2dec()
```

Comment: `a = a/2-0.5` produces a number that does not match `a % 2 == 0` nor `a % 2 == 1` -> infinite loop

Comment: Actually see what happens is if the modulus of 2 (remainder in division when divided by 2) is equal to 1, that's the only time it'll run that code. So when 65 is divided by 2, there's a remainder of one, 65/2 is equal to 32.5, 32.5 minus 0.5 leaves 32.

Comment: except `65/2 == 32` because it is an integer division. I would `(a - 1) / 2` instead.

Comment: No, that would be `65//2` <- note the double forward-slash. (Literally just checked in the python interpreter) I'm using v3.4.2

Comment: `I'm using v3.4.2` in that case then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Oh....welp. It seems the problem was actually that I somehow installed two versions of pythons and I guess they had been interfering with each other. Reason I'm not deleting this Q is because I'm sure I'm not the only one who's made this mistake. However, others have probably made this mistake in an effort to ensure compatibility between versions. Bad idea.

Comment: The reason was that division in Python 3 (the version this is written to) is float, while in 2.x, it was integer division. This meant that your divisions were doing nothing, resulting in an infinite loop, hence the 'hang'.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was not aware of this difference. Is there a way to write conditional code based on version running?

Comment: The 'proper division' functionality is backported and can be enabled in compatible versions of 2.x with [`from __future__ import division`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). More generally, you might want to look at [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#module-lib2to3).